# How to find an object with a certain property value in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, web, extjs

I have an array of objects:

```
var allButtons = [
    buttonA,
    buttonВ,
    buttonС,
    "->"
];
```

This objects can have the property 'hidden' which can be true or false.

**I need to discover (in an optimal way), whether any of this 'buttons' have hidden === false** (in other words, are visible).

Now i use this primitive approach:

```
someOfButtonsIsVisible = false;

Ext.each(allButtons, function (item){
    if(item.hidden === false) {
        someOfButtonsIsVisible = true;
    }
});
```

But in this case i have to go through all objects and check their 'hidden' property.

**Is there a better way to know whether any of objects in array have hidden === false?**

Answer (score 2):

Use *array.prototype.some*:

```js
var someOfButtonsIsVisible = allButtons.some(button => button.hidden === false);
```

It can also be done with *array.prototype.every*:

```js
var someOfButtonsIsVisible = !allButtons.every(button => button.hidden === true);
```

But in your case, *array.prototype.some* make more sense

Answer (score 2):

Use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function.

Find will traverse your array, and stop once it found the value wanted. You can then test the return value if it's different from `undefined`.

**Edit**: If your goal is to identitfy if at least one (or some) value are `false`, then `array.some()`is better. If you goal is to retrieve the value which match `hidden === false` then `array.find()` is better.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case of sequential search. 
No matter what you use the time complexity will vary between O(1)(best case) to O(n)(worst case).

Now if you can sort the array so that the visible buttons are added to the top then the search logic will always have a time complexity of O(1)

Note: break the loop after satisfying the condition.